# Cosmos DB, What will happen If I update some item when query with SkipToken?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

If I query items from CosmosDB with SkipToken,

Like Pseudo code:

```
do{
   var page = Query();
   foreach(var item in page)
   {
      Update(item);
   }
}while(HasNextPage());
```

The `page` I get may not be complete, which means I will miss some item.

But if I wait a moment after `Update`
Like:

```
do{
   var page = Query();
   foreach(var item in page)
   {
      Update(item);
   }

   // difference here:
   WaitAMoment();
}while(HasNextPage());
```

, the error will not happen, and I will get the complete page with all I need.

So what happened to such a process?

Comment: Could you pls add the `Query()` details? With the sql, I may try to reproduce the problem in my side.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to wait in code as such, **this functionality is handled by CosmosDB internally**. Check out [Pagination in SDKs of Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-pagination#:%7E:text=Each%20page%27s%20results%20is%20generated,query%20by%20setting%20the%20MaxItemCount%20.) and, for example sake, I am adding code of handling server-side pagination in C# below (*to get a gist of how it works*):

```
private static async Task QueryPartitionedContainerInParallelAsync(Container container)
        {
            List<Family> familiesSerial = new List<Family>();
            string queryText = "SELECT * FROM Families";

            // 0 maximum parallel tasks, effectively serial execution
            QueryRequestOptions options = new QueryRequestOptions() { MaxBufferedItemCount = 100 };
            options.MaxConcurrency = 0;
            using (FeedIterator<Family> query = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Family>(
                queryText,
                requestOptions: options))
            {
                while (query.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    foreach (Family family in await query.ReadNextAsync())
                    {
                        familiesSerial.Add(family);
                    }
                }
            }

            Assert("Parallel Query expected two families", familiesSerial.ToList().Count == 2);

            // 1 maximum parallel tasks, 1 dedicated asynchronous task to continuously make REST calls
            List<Family> familiesParallel1 = new List<Family>();

            options.MaxConcurrency = 1;
            using (FeedIterator<Family> query = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Family>(
                queryText,
                requestOptions: options))
            {
                while (query.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    foreach (Family family in await query.ReadNextAsync())
                    {
                        familiesParallel1.Add(family);
                    }
                }
            }

            Assert("Parallel Query expected two families", familiesParallel1.ToList().Count == 2);
            AssertSequenceEqual("Parallel query returns result out of order compared to serial execution", familiesSerial, familiesParallel1);


            // 10 maximum parallel tasks, a maximum of 10 dedicated asynchronous tasks to continuously make REST calls
            List<Family> familiesParallel10 = new List<Family>();

            options.MaxConcurrency = 10;
            using (FeedIterator<Family> query = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Family>(
                queryText,
                requestOptions: options))
            {
                while (query.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    foreach (Family family in await query.ReadNextAsync())
                    {
                        familiesParallel10.Add(family);
                    }
                }
            }

            Assert("Parallel Query expected two families", familiesParallel10.ToList().Count == 2);
            AssertSequenceEqual("Parallel query returns result out of order compared to serial execution", familiesSerial, familiesParallel10);
        }
```